How to validate the end time is not greater than start time with zod validation in react ts?
I used react-hook-form with zod validation. I have an problem with custom validation which is the end time is not grater than start time.
I try with this schema
  const ProductMesSchema = z
    .object({
      id: z.number().optional(),
      shift_name: z
        .string({ message: "Please enter a valid Shift Name." })
        .min(1, { message: "Please enter a valid Shift Name." })
        .max(100, {
          message:
            "Shift name exceeds the maximum allowed length of 100 characters.",
        })
        .refine((name) => /^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$/.test(name), {
          message: "Special characters are not allowed.",
        }),
      shift_type: z.number({ message: "Please select a valid Shift Type." }),
      leave: z
        .array(z.string({ message: "Please select leave day" }))
        .min(1, { message: "Please select leave days" }),
      start_time: z.custom((val) => dayjs.isDayjs(val) && val.isValid(), {
        message: "Please enter a valid Start Time.",
      }),
      end_time: z.custom((val) => dayjs.isDayjs(val) && val.isValid(), {
        message: "Please enter a valid End Time",
      }),
    })
    .refine((val) => dayjs(val.start_time).isBefore(dayjs(val.end_time)), {
      message: "Please ensure the Start time is earlier than the End time.",
      path: ["start_time"],
    });

  const methods = useForm<IShiftMaster>({
    defaultValues: props.initialValues,
    resolver: zodResolver(ProductMesSchema),
    mode: "onChange",
  });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IShiftMaster> = (val) => {
    console.log(val);
    if (val.id) {
      dispatch(editShiftMasterStart(val));
    } else {
      dispatch(createShiftMasterStart(val));
    }
  };

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form
        ref={props.formRef}
        onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        className="form_content"
      >
        <DevTool control={methods.control} /> {/* set up the dev tool */}
        <TextInputFieldC name="shift_name" label="Shift Name" />
        <Select
          options={shiftTypeOptions}
          name="shift_type"
          label="Shift Type"
          value={
            shiftTypeOptions?.find(
              (val) => val.value === methods.getValues("shift_type")
            ) ?? null
          }
          onChange={(_, val) => {
            const value = val as AutocompleteOption;
            methods.setValue("shift_type", value?.value, {
              shouldValidate: true,
            });
          }}
        />
        <TimePickersC
          name="start_time"
          label="Start time"
          maxTime={dayjs(methods.getValues("end_time"))}
        />
        <TimePickersC
          name="end_time"
          label="End time"
          minTime={dayjs(methods.getValues("start_time"))}
          onBlur={() => {
            methods.trigger();
          }}
        />
        <MultiSelectC
          options={weekdays}
          name="leave"
          label="Leave"
          value={
            weekdays?.filter((val) =>
              methods.getValues("leave")?.includes(val.value)
            ) ?? []
          }
          onChange={(_, val) => {
            const value = val as AutocompleteOption[];

            methods.setValue(
              "leave",
              value.map((leave) => leave.value) as unknown as string,
              {
                shouldValidate: true,
              }
            );
          }}
        />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );


this is not working to me. Even I try to log inside the refine. It doesn't rendered.
How can I do this validation?
These are my full code. The refine validation working on after entering the other fields. How can I resole this issue?

onBlur event handler for the end_time field triggers validation specifically for the end_time field using methods.trigger('end_time').
updated schema:
import { z } from 'zod';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

const ProductMesSchema = z
  .object({
    id: z.number().optional(),
    shift_name: z
      .string({ message: "Please enter a valid Shift Name." })
      .min(1, { message: "Please enter a valid Shift Name." })
      .max(100, {
        message: "Shift name exceeds the maximum allowed length of 100 characters.",
      })
      .refine((name) => /^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$/.test(name), {
        message: "Special characters are not allowed.",
      }),
    shift_type: z.number({ message: "Please select a valid Shift Type." }),
    leave: z
      .array(z.string({ message: "Please select leave day" }))
      .min(1, { message: "Please select leave days" }),
    start_time: z.custom((val) => dayjs.isDayjs(val) && val.isValid(), {
      message: "Please enter a valid Start Time.",
    }),
    end_time: z.custom((val) => dayjs.isDayjs(val) && val.isValid(), {
      message: "Please enter a valid End Time",
    }),
  })
  .refine((val) => dayjs(val.start_time).isBefore(dayjs(val.end_time)), {
    message: "Please ensure the Start time is earlier than the End time.",
    path: ["end_time"], // Specify the path to show the error on the end_time field
  });

import { useForm, FormProvider, Controller, SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import { ProductMesSchema } from './path-to-your-schema'; // Adjust the import path
import { DevTool } from '@hookform/devtools'; // Optional: for dev tool

const YourFormComponent = (props) => {
  const methods = useForm<IShiftMaster>({
    defaultValues: props.initialValues,
    resolver: zodResolver(ProductMesSchema),
    mode: "onChange",
  });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IShiftMaster> = (val) => {
    console.log(val);
    if (val.id) {
      dispatch(editShiftMasterStart(val));
    } else {
      dispatch(createShiftMasterStart(val));
    }
  };

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form
        ref={props.formRef}
        onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        className="form_content"
      >
        <DevTool control={methods.control} /> {/* set up the dev tool */}
        <TextInputFieldC name="shift_name" label="Shift Name" />
        <Select
          options={shiftTypeOptions}
          name="shift_type"
          label="Shift Type"
          value={
            shiftTypeOptions?.find(
              (val) => val.value === methods.getValues("shift_type")
            ) ?? null
          }
          onChange={(_, val) => {
            const value = val as AutocompleteOption;
            methods.setValue("shift_type", value?.value, {
              shouldValidate: true,
            });
          }}
        />
        <TimePickersC
          name="start_time"
          label="Start time"
          maxTime={dayjs(methods.getValues("end_time"))}
        />
        <TimePickersC
          name="end_time"
          label="End time"
          minTime={dayjs(methods.getValues("start_time"))}
          onBlur={() => {
            methods.trigger('end_time'); // Trigger validation for end_time field
          }}
        />
        <MultiSelectC
          options={weekdays}
          name="leave"
          label="Leave"
          value={
            weekdays?.filter((val) =>
              methods.getValues("leave")?.includes(val.value)
            ) ?? []
          }
          onChange={(_, val) => {
            const value = val as AutocompleteOption[];

            methods.setValue(
              "leave",
              value.map((leave) => leave.value) as unknown as string,
              {
                shouldValidate: true,
              }
            );
          }}
        />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
};

export default YourFormComponent;


Yup. It's working fine. But the refine error shows after submit. But I need to show
while entering end_time.

added onChange handler for the end_time field triggers validation using the trigger function.

I trigger it on onblure. but it's not working until the all fields are complete.

can you please provide more information what exactly you want so I can get better idea

I update all my codes without the internal components.

please check updated

Nope. It's not working. The refine error triggers only after clearing all errors. Otherwise, it's not triggered.
